# How to remove border from previous sibling?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a trick to add a border between navigation items

```
li {
  &:not(.active) {
    &::before {
    border-bottom: grey;
    bottom: 0;
    content: '';
    height: 1px;
    left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;

    :host-context(.minified) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
```

It works fine. You can see the yellow marked line.
If navigation is active i do not add this border.

If the navigation link is active, i would like to remove the border from previous sibling. You can see the red arrow.

[image]

Anybody ideas how can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)

Comment: previous or next?

Comment: @Dekel have seen this but didn't find an answer to my concrete question

Comment: Please double check that question. Answer is there.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i think i will be pervious, because i add bottom-border. But a solution can work another way...

Comment: if you *think* then share your full code so we can also think with you

Comment: @Dekel there is probably no previous selector but this seems an XY problem. He think he need a previous selector but I am pretty sure we don't need it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree. There is probably a solution with next/current selector (instead of previous). Juri - are you able to provide a complete working example (and not just css block)?

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean by full code? my angular app with 3 different navigation components with whole css? really?

Comment: something like + li:not(.active) { &::before but it doesn't work

Comment: a code needed to us in order to see things working, no need ALL the code. We need an MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TemaniAfif hard to reproduce. The solution should be really simple => only if next is not .active But it is not working. Cant get it

Comment: @Juri if you want help you should invest the time it takes to create mcve. It's that simple.

Comment: @TemaniAfif here we go https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mQqQrm

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/tzmh1gb9/

Comment: @TemaniAfif thx, good idea, last element needs a line at bottom?

Comment: ues last child selector and add that line using `:after`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the divider at the top of the `li` and remove the first divider with `li:first-child:after`

Now, when hovering you can access the next `li` with `+` and set the background to be transparent.

Here's an example:

```css
html, body{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul {
  border-right: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
  width: 180px;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 10px #e5e5e5;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

li:after{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  top: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 130px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
}

li:first-child:after{
  height: 0px;
}


li:hover {
  color: #13A83E;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

li:hover + li:after {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Dashboard</li>
  <li>Assets</li>
  <li>Devices</li>
  <li>More</li>
  <li>Options</li>
</ul>
```